# Damage in Circuit

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis

i open my dameged telephone that works on battery. I found that there is a piece named as SA is explon so i have to replace it but i don't know what is the meaning of SA. In the right side there is another SA piece so any help plz

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it "exploded" or is simply not populated? Unless you cleaned it, it looks fine to me. It's normal to find unpopulated components on boards, either from finding what they had was overkill or slight changes in design over time.
It looks like there is writing on the component to the right, just hard to read. If you can, lookup the model# on that component. No matter the component, it has certain specifications that must be met when replaced.

Comment: Ok, I have a diode is short named as O607

Comment: You mean it failed shorted, as in is conducting both ways? Or has it failed in some other manner?

Comment: It give a short circuit on buzzer

Comment: I will assume you tested it properly (a diode can be viewed as a short in one direction, but an open in another). I can't walk you through the whole repair process. You need to work backwards from the issue, whatever it may be. You should measure voltages at known voltage points, and identify any potential issues from there. If one component is dead or failed in some form, you should check other components before and after as they may have been the cause or may have been damaged. If you have any specific questions pop back here.

Comment: SA101 and SA104 would appear to be some kind of overvoltage protection.  Look at the symbol next to each part - looks like a schematic representation of a spark gap.  Probably a varistor.  If it has blown, then likely other parts died with it.

Answer (score 2):

SA's are surge arrestors for external power sources.

If shorted in both polarities, then replace with same.

Diodes start with D, not O designation.

Comment: Is there any replacments for it as using another type of diode !?

Comment: not unless you identify p.n.

Comment: On the PCB it's D

Comment: Sorry i talk about a diodet that i have named as SS14S

Comment: that shud be in question .... any diode as DIODE SCHOTTKY 40V 1A DO214AC

Answer (score 0):

SA104 is a optical Switches, transmissive, phototransistor output actuator mounted PCB type. Some kind of IC. (It just a code). You can learn more about it on http://my.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Omron-Electronics/EE-SA104/?qs=SMvRj3nRgHWxDwyoSkNmKg==

Comment: Sorry it's named as SS14S

Comment: @WaltPeter In this case "SA" stands for "surge arrestor"